# Replicate similar structured macro definitions with LaTeX3

Tags: macros, latex3

Is any posssibility create similar structured macro? For example, in MWE I have a `\creator` and I want create same defined macro `\lecturer`, so it possible via replacing word `creator` to `lecturer`. And if I have many identical same macro it is boring. I need to somehow define the listing at the program level, such `creator, lecturer,practicer` and then multiply the user level macros `\creator`, `\lecturer,` \practicer`...

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\int_new:N \l_creator_int
\NewDocumentCommand\creator{ O{} m}
{
    \int_incr:N \l_creator_int
    \cs_new_protected:cpn {creator\int_use:N\l_creator_int}{#2}
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {} {\cs_new_protected:cpn {creator\int_use:N\l_creator_int email}{#1}}
    
}

%\int_new:N \l_lecturer_int
%\NewDocumentCommand\creator{ O{} m}
%{
%    \int_incr:N \l_lecturer_int
%    \cs_new_protected:cpn {lecturer\int_use:N\l_lecturer_int}{#2}
%    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {} {\cs_new_protected:cpn {lecturer\int_use:N\l_lecturer_int email}{#1}}
%    
%}

%...

% same for \practicer and other
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\creator[]{First}
\creator{Second}
\creator[mail@internet.com]{Third}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why don't you adapt the names of your commands? skillmon showed you how you should name them and corrected lots of stuff, and  you seem to ignored everything.

Comment: You've already been advised that you should *not* use functions (that is `\cs_new...`) but token list variables for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong approach. To begin with, you shouldn't use *functions* (aka *macros*) for storing data, but token list variables or, in this case, sequences.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\creator}{O{}m}
 {
  \sk_class_data_add:nnn { creator } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lecturer}{O{}m}
 {
  \sk_class_data_add:nnn { lecturer } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\retrieve}{mm}
 {% #1 is the type, creator or lecturer
  % #2 is the index
  \seq_item:cn { g_sk_class_#1_name_seq } { #2 }
  \tl_if_blank:eF { \seq_item:cn { g_sk_class_#1_email_seq } { #2 } }
   { ~ \texttt{\seq_item:cn { g_sk_class_#1_email_seq } { #2 }} }
 }


\seq_new:N \g_sk_class_creator_name_seq
\seq_new:N \g_sk_class_creator_email_seq
\seq_new:N \g_sk_class_lecturer_name_seq
\seq_new:N \g_sk_class_lecturer_email_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sk_class_data_add:nnn
 {
  % add the name to the proper sequence variable
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_sk_class_#1_name_seq } { #3 }
  % add the email to the proper sequence variable
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_sk_class_#1_email_seq } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\creator[]{First}
\creator{Second}
\creator[mail@internet.com]{Third}

\lecturer{Me}
\lecturer[]{You}
\lecturer[bela.lugosi@example.com]{Count Dracula}

\retrieve{creator}{3}

\retrieve{lecturer}{2}

\retrieve{lecturer}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You.It is possible to concatate two sequences (name and email) into comma separated  one such `name1 (email1), name2, name3 (email3)`?

Comment: @sergiokapone The `\retrieve` macro was just given as an example. Is your aim to *print* the list of creators that way?

Comment: My aim both, print comma separated list of creators with email (if it exist), and use creator name by itself in different place. Now I think about creating some subsequent. Thank you. I will try

Comment: Very useful answer!